# Vertical custom validator for FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I want the total to be exactky 100. but this Validator doesn't work. What is wrong in my code?

```
export class CustomValidators { 
  public static verticalTotal(total: number, refControl: string) {
    return (control: FormArray): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const arrayValue = control.value || [];
      let actualTotal = 0;
      control.controls.forEach(ctrl => {
        actualTotal += +(ctrl.get(refControl).value);
     });
  return actualTotal !== total ?
     { verticalTotal: true,
       message: `Total should be ${total}, not ${actualTotal}`
     } : null;
    };
   } 
}
```

I apply the validator like this

```
 this.itemForm = this.fb.group({
  subsidiaries: this.fb.array([], {
    validators: [CustomValidators.verticalTotal(100, 'percent')]
  })
}, { validators: [] });

const line = this.fb.group({
  'name': ['', []],
  'percent': [0, []]
});
(this.itemForm.get('subsidiaries') as FormArray).push(line);

this.itemForm.get('subsidiaries').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: your code works, I make a stackblitz with your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-umarkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. NOTE: I don't like this `const line = this.fb.group({})` better make a function that return a FormGroup

Comment: You are right. My code works. Except the object I return doesnot contain a definition for message. it had to be `{ verticalTotal: {valid: false,
       message: `Total should be ${total}, not ${actualTotal}`}
     } : null;` so I can set the error message inside the component template

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Eliseo You are right. My code works. Except the object I return did not contain a definition for message. it had to be

```
   {
    verticalTotal: { valid: false,
                     message: `Total should be ${total}, not ${actualTotal}`}
    } : null;
```

instead of what was in my code. This way I could set the error message inside the component template.

**EDITS**: another thing I dit was to use the value, not the `actualTotal += +(ctrl.get(refControl).value);`. Here's the edited part

```
 arrayValue.forEach(ctrl => {
    actualTotal += +(ctrl[refControl]);
  });
```

Comment: I updated the stackblitz as you say, and work too. But. be carefully, I remember that in old versions of Angular (I can not remember if in Angular 6 or Angular 7) it was true that the "value" was different e.g. `form.get('something).value` was different than `form.value.something`. But this was resolved in Angular 9 -It's possible than in Angular 8 too-

Comment: In all my projects, I upgraded to 11 so I'm using Angular 11

Comment: then, I don't know what happens :(

Comment: the problem is solved now it works. Don't worry